# How to Find the Repeated/Duplicate Value in a List in Mysql Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql

My list is like [1,2,3,2,5,2]
Needed result is 2 occurs 3 times.
I am using mysql stored procedure.
i tried find in set in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

use `aggregation` and `group by`

```
select no, count(*)
from tablename
group by no
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want only repeated values

```
SELECT num, COUNT(num) AS c FROM yourTable GROUP BY num HAVING c>1
```

Answer (score 0):

One trick is to replace 2 in the list and check the size after against before. (though I suspect your list may be a bit more than single digits)

for example

```
set @a = '1,2,3,5,2,6';

select  length(@A) ,
            length(replace(@a,'2','')),
            length(@A) - length(replace(@a,'2','')) 

+------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| length(@A) | length(replace(@a,'2','')) | length(@A) - length(replace(@a,'2','')) |
+------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|         11 |                          9 |                                       2 |
+------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

if the numbers are of varying length divide the difference by the length of the search item

```
set @a = '1,2,11,12,13,15,12,16,12,100';
set @b = '12';
select  length(@A) ,
            length(replace(@a,@b,'')),
            (length(@A) - length(replace(@a,@b,''))) / length(@b);

+------------+---------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| length(@A) | length(replace(@a,@b,'')) | (length(@A) - length(replace(@a,@b,''))) / length(@b) |
+------------+---------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|         28 |                        22 |                                                3.0000 |
+------------+---------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Yes, Trick Worked only for single digit.

Comment: I need for Multiple Digit.

Comment: You should amend your question to include a more representative sample of your data.

Comment: If the numbers are of varying length then divide the difference by the length of the search item - see edit.